# Creating graph from polygons takes too long with large number of vertices

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, graph

I am trying to build a graph out of multipolygons. The code works fine when I don't have large amount of vertices but with 1M it is not satisfying. Any performance improvement suggestions?

```
public Graph(List<Polygon> PolygonsSet)
    {
        edges = new List<Edge>();
        graphID = Guid.NewGuid();
        //Setting up Graph instance by adding vertices, edges and polygons
        foreach (Polygon Polygon in PolygonsSet)
        {
            List<Vertex> vertices = Polygon.vertices;

            // Clear pre-existing edges in the case this is an updating process.
            Polygon.edges.Clear();

            //If there is only one polygon, treat it as boundary
            if (PolygonsSet.Count() == 1)
            {
                Polygon.isBoundary = true;
            }

            //If first and last point of vertices list are the same, remove last.
            if (vertices.First().Equals(vertices.Last()) && vertices.Count() > 1)
            {
                vertices = vertices.Take(vertices.Count() - 1).ToList();
            }


            //For each point, creates vertex and associated edge and adds them
            //to the polygons Dictionary
            int vertexCount = vertices.Count();

            // If valid polygon
            if (vertexCount >= 3)
            {
                int newId = GetNextId();
                for (var j = 0; j < vertexCount; j++)
                {
                    int next_index = (j + 1) % vertexCount;
                    Vertex vertex = vertices[j];
                    Vertex next_vertex = vertices[next_index];
                    Edge edge = new Edge(vertex, next_vertex);

                    //If is a valid polygon, add id to vertex and
                    //edge to vertices dictionary
                    if (vertexCount > 2)
                    {
                        vertex.polygonId = newId;
                        next_vertex.polygonId = newId;
                        Polygon gPol = new Polygon();
                        if (polygons.TryGetValue(newId, out gPol))
                        {
                            gPol.edges.Add(edge);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Polygon.edges.Add(edge);
                            Polygon.id = newId;
                            polygons.Add(newId, Polygon);
                        }
                    }
                    AddEdge(edge);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

and AddEdge method is;

```
public void AddEdge(Edge edge)
    {
        List<Edge> startEdgesList = new List<Edge>();
        List<Edge> endEdgesList = new List<Edge>();
        if (graph.TryGetValue(edge.StartVertex, out startEdgesList))
        {
            if (!startEdgesList.Contains(edge)) { startEdgesList.Add(edge); }
        }
        else
        {
            graph.Add(edge.StartVertex, new List<Edge>() { edge });
        }

        if (graph.TryGetValue(edge.EndVertex, out endEdgesList))
        {
            if (!endEdgesList.Contains(edge)) { endEdgesList.Add(edge); }
        }
        else
        {
            graph.Add(edge.EndVertex, new List<Edge>() { edge });
        }

        if (!edges.Contains(edge)) { edges.Add(edge); }
    }
```

Code works fine, my only concern is performance.

I tried to simplify the polygons and even used convex hull to reduce the workload but in some cases I need to use the polygon as it is.

So any help will be appreciated...

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: added asp.net-core as a tag. Using  .NET Core 2.1

Comment: @TaW, since this is pure logic not involving UI operations, this additional tag is not required. Here, with [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) a mathematical structure is meant, not a graphic.

Comment: He still seems to be targetting some libraries which he ought to have mentioned..

Comment: @TaW what does it have to do with it. I guess the question was clean and detailed enough to understand what I was looking for. I am also using EF Core 2.1 on my project but what does it have to do with the answer?

Comment: Now that you have added the asp.net-core tag it is fine. Before it was incomplete as one would have to research just what those classes are and where they come from. This is what tags are for: Helping to determine if one can help __from the question overview page__  If it had actually been just about math it would have been off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code lines starting with `if (vertexCount > 2)`, you test the vertext count, but the count did not change since the last test `if (vertexCount >= 3)`. Drop this second `if`.
Then you create a new polygon with `Polygon gPol = new Polygon();`. This polygon gets replaced immediately afterwards by the `out` parameter in `polygons.TryGetValue(newId, out gPol)`.
Either `TryGetValue` yields `true`, then `gPol` become the polygon found in the collection, or `TryGetValue` yields `false` and `gPol` becomes `null`. Do not assign `gPol`

```
Polygon gPol;
if (polygons.TryGetValue(newId, out gPol)) ...
```

Or use the C# 7.0 syntax

```
if (polygons.TryGetValue(newId, out Polygon gPol)) ...
```

In the `else` case, you should create a new polygon (because `gPol` is `null`). However, you can simplify this code, because the edge is added in both cases:

```
if (!polygons.TryGetValue(newId, out Polygon gPol)) {
    gPol = new Polygon { id = newId };
    polygons.Add(newId, gPol);
}
gPol.edges.Add(edge);
```

---

You also seem to confuse `Polygon` with `gPol`.

---

Since `newId` gets created before the for-loop, you can move the code finding or creating the polyon out of the loop

```
int vertexCount = vertices.Count();
if (vertexCount >= 3)
{
    int newId = GetNextId();
    if (!polygons.TryGetValue(newId, out Polygon gPol)) {
        gPol = new Polygon { id = newId };
        polygons.Add(newId, gPol);
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < vertexCount; j++)
    {
        int next_index = (j + 1) % vertexCount;
        Vertex vertex = vertices[j];
        Vertex next_vertex = vertices[next_index];
        Edge edge = new Edge(vertex, next_vertex);

        vertex.polygonId = newId;
        next_vertex.polygonId = newId;
        gPol.edges.Add(edge);
        AddEdge(edge);
    }
}
```

---

In `AddEdge` you are repeating the same error of overwriting the lists just created by `TryGetValue`.

Comment: Thank you Oliver, I couldn't understand the AddEdge part since i have many conditions.

Comment: Exactly the same poblem with `graph.TryGetValue(edge.StartVertex, out startEdgesList)` and `graph.TryGetValue(edge.EndVertex, out endEdgesList)` as I explained with `polygons.TryGetValue(newId, out gPol)`. The `out` parameter replaces the value of `startEdgesList` and `endEdgesList` either with an existing list or with `null`, so the two `new List<Edge>()` are useless.

Comment: It improved the performance little bit but still takes a long time. any other approaches to make it faster? I went through 133493 vertices in 12mins which is still too long.

Comment: I also worked with polygons but stored only their vertices as the edge-information is inherently contained in the vertex-information. It would save you memory and time not to store the redundant edge information.